# Regular expression to find numbers inside HTML tags

Tags: regex

I need to wrap numbers inside HTML tags without affecting attributes.

So far, all I could get is selecting what's inside a tag only, digits and non digital characters too :(

Here's the regular expression I'm using :

`/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)/g`

[Here's the code at RegExr](http://regexr.com?361gc)!

I'll be using jQuery to parse it. [This is the closest I could get jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamedoe/hDVpe/).

How to make this regular expression look only for numbers inside html tags?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Don't use regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Use a DOM parser and traverse the text nodes - then apply the replacement only on those.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Guess it could be more precise. How to direct jQuery to look only on text nodes? This could make regex more effective.

Answer (score 1):

This matches 123 in `<div>123</div>` for example:

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)|(?<=^|>)\d+(?=<|$)
```

This regex was edited from the link you provided: http://regexr.com/?361gc

Comment: Thanks but it's still not selection numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

This selects only numbers within html tags. It also works on multi line text.

```
(?!<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b[^><]*>[^><0-9]*)([0-9]+)(?=[^><0-9]*<)
```

You can test it [here](http://regexr.com?3623j).

But please be advised that `<html>` and `<body>` tags will match the pattern you asked for, so when you are running a complete html document through this regex, most or all numbers will be matching.

Testing on your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDVpe/10/) I changed it to this:

```
$('body').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace(/(?!<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b[^><]*>[^><0-9]*)([0-9]+)(?=[^><0-9]*<)/gim, '<span>$1</span>');   
    });
});
```

So now it only runs on the elements of the body and not the whole document.  Is that giving the expected result?

Comment: Same, it's still not selecting numbers only.